# Why do I get these errors?

Tags: drush

I am getting a variety of errors when I try to use Drush and nothing seems to be working. I am able to run `drush` and see the help commands indicating that I have it installed; otherwise, I can't get anything to work. I get the following error when trying to update a module as an example:

> Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   Command pm-update needs the following modules installed/enabled to run: update.
>   The drush command 'pm-update insert' could not be executed.
>   A Drupal installation directory could not be found

When I check the `drush status` output, I get the following, but it doesn't appear to have any of the other relevant site info that is shown in other examples (e.g. theme name, site name, etc.).

```
 PHP configuration     :  /etc/php.ini
 Drush version         :  4.5
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :
```

Drush is currently installed in my home directory on a BlueHost shared account and my primary site is in the public_html directory; I have an additional site with a separate Drupal version and separate database in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call drush when you are within your Drupal folder. Otherwise drush does not know where your database is and so on.

```
cd /public_html/site2
```

Alternatively, you can set up a .drush/aliases.drushrc.php (Google should be able to tell you more about it) but that's probably not worth the effort in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I tried going into my public_html to call drush while in that folder and I get the following error: 
    `durangp4@durangotherapist.com [~/public_html]# drush pm-update insert  
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]

Error: Cannot redeclare system_help() (previously declared in
/home1/durangp4/public_html/modules/system/system.module:46) in
/home1/durangp4/public_html/modules/modules/system/system.module,
line 105 `  
Thanks

Comment: @Kory This means that you did it right, but that there is a fatal error in your drupal installation. You should not be able to view your site. Try to re-download drupal core.

Comment: Thank you @googletorp for your assistance and prompt reply! I was running 6.22 but my site was accessible -i.e. no WSOD.  I just updated to Drupal 6.25 and ran update.php.  Update was successful and shows up to date in my available updates reports.  I tried drush again and am still getting the same error:
    `Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: Cannot redeclare system_help() (previously declared in
/home1/durangp4/public_html/modules/system/system.module:46) in
/home1/durangp4/public_html/modules/modules/system/system.module, line 105`

Comment: @Kory Ah I see, you have the system module twice, `/modules/system` and `/modules/modules/system`, you should only have one of them.

Comment: Thanks @googletorp! Wow and thank you for helping me spot that... So I tried removing my duplicate modules folder and I am now getting a WSOD with the following error:   `Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'modules/modules/system/system.admin.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home1/durangp4/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 348`  <br/> Any ideas where that can be fixed?

Comment: Try running update.php, that usually helps. If not, you need to look into the system table in your database and manually remove the double /modules/modules path for all modules which have it. Once you did that, you will also need to clear the cache_bootstrap table and then you should be back up and running I hope :)

Comment: @Berdir Thank you and googletorp both so much for all of your assistance!  You saved my a** today... I couldnt run update.php because of the WSOD but I was able to go into the database and manually deleted all duplicate module/module instances in the system table, clear caches and get the site back.  From there, I was able to run a module update with drush and see the magic that everyone talked about!  I cant thank you enough for a great site and great help!